# Metadata for a custom logger that uses string.Format under the hood

Tags: c#, visual-studio

So I have a logger that defaults to plain old `Console.WriteLine()`, but it's unit-testable, and in a Windows app, to name one example, I can use a different implementation to write output to a window that the user can see.  The interface looks like this:

```
public interface ILog
{
    void WriteLine(string text, params object[] args);
}
```

So far, so boilerplate.  There is something else I'd like to do, however.  In Visual Studio, if you use `string.Format` or `Console.WriteLine`, the editor and the compiler match the arguments in `args` with the contents of your string, and warn you if the two fail to match up.  Plus, the `{0}, {1:0.00}, ...` components of your string are displayed with nice highlighting to show where your arguments will show up in the string you're building.

Is there some kind of metadata I can feed to the compiler to let it know that my `ILog.WriteLine` method should behave in the same way as `string.Format` or `Console.WriteLine`?  I've searched around but found nothing yet.

Comment: I think the nice syntax highlighting you see is from Resharper

Comment: Yup, that's ReSharper doing.